# Determining python memory usage on embedded system?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why a Python program I have is infinitely gobbling up memory...

The problem is that this is an embedded system that doesn't have access to development tools like `pdb`.

I also can't install new python modules on it like `memory_profiler`.

How can I do this using pure Python?

Comment: `infinitely gobbling up memory` are you appending a ton of stuff to lists etcetera in a main loop? i.e. - something that won't get garbage collected / go out of scope. That'll do it.

Comment: If you have a fully functional code you may want to take it to [Stack Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as that would be a good place to have someone look at your code and probably point out any issues with your program that could be causing memory leaks.

Comment: One way would be to periodically check the size of the objects you use in your program. You can write that on a logfile for further analysis. If you use too many objects, it is impractical.